# Tkinter (python) Variable vacía

Tags: python, tkinter

Al executar el siguiente código:

```
from Tkinter import *



def RegistrarP():

    def GuardarP():
        print ("Eres una " + svnombreRP.get())

    ventanaRP = Tk()
    ventanaRP.geometry("600x600+720+320")
    ventanaRP.title("StackBlueD")

    svnombreRP = StringVar()
    nombreRP = Label (ventanaRP,text="Nombre Perfil").place(x=10,y=30)
    ctnombreRP = Entry(ventanaRP,textvariable=svnombreRP).place(x=150,y=30)

    guardarRP = Button(ventanaRP, text="Guardar Perfil", command = GuardarP).place(x=400,y=200)

    ventanaRP.mainloop()

ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x600+700+300")
ventana.title("StackBlueD")

cargarP = Button(ventana, text="Cargar Perfil").place(x=200,y=200)
registrarP = Button(ventana, text="Registrar Perfil", command =    RegistrarP).place(x=200,y=300)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Se abre una ventana y a darle en el botón `Registrar perfil` se abre una subventana para introducir una cadena de texto en un `Entry` y a darle al botón guardar se imprime por consola la cadena introducida en el `Entry`, en mi caso la cadena siempre está vacía meta lo que le meta. ¿Porque ocurre eso y no guarda la cadena?

Declaro una variable tipo `StringVar` que tiene el método `variable.get()` que sirve para coger el valor de la variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que la ventana que creas con `RegistrarP()` no es una ventana hija de `ventana`. Puedes solucionarlo fácilmente usando `Toplevel()` para crear la ventana hija:

```
import Tkinter as tk


def registrar_p():

    def guardar_p():
        print ("Eres una " + svnombre_rp.get())

    ventana_rp = tk.Toplevel(ventana)
    ventana_rp.geometry("600x600+720+320")
    ventana_rp.title("StackBlueD")

    svnombre_rp = tk.StringVar(ventana_rp)
    tk.Label (ventana_rp, text="Nombre Perfil").place(x=10,y=30)
    tk.Entry(ventana_rp, textvariable=svnombre_rp).place(x=150,y=30)

    tk.Button(
        ventana_rp, text="Guardar Perfil", command=guardar_p
        ).place(x=400,y=200)


ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x600+700+300")
ventana.title("StackBlueD")

tk.Button(ventana, text="Cargar Perfil").place(x=200,y=200)
tk.Button(
    ventana, text="Registrar Perfil", command=registrar_p
    ).place(x=200,y=300)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Si te fijas, en tu código original, si cierras la ventana principal con `ventanaRP` abierta, esta última no se cierra. Esto ocurre porque es una ventana (una instancia) independiente de `ventana`. Ahora `ventanaRP` es una ventana hija de `ventana` y al cerrar esta última se cierra también su ventana hija si está abierta.

Comment: Tu solución es correcta, muchas gracias, estoy aprendiendo python con tkinter.

Comment: sobre ese código... la linea " ventanaRP.mainloop()" no es necesaria, ¿no? Y por otra parte, cual es el motivo por el cual no funcionaba el svnombreRP.get()?